# How can I check for the actual time in a Script?

Tags: shell-script

I want to check the time in a script. If it's between 06:00 am and 12:00 am it should output morning. If it's between 01:00 pm and 06:00 pm it should output afternoon. Between 07:00 pm and 10:00 pm it should outuput evening and between 11:00 pm and 05:00 am it should output night.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Prüft anhand der Zeit ob es Vormittag, Nachmittag, Abend oder Nacht ist
# $1 ist der Dateiname
# bash MehrfachSelektionScript.sh datei.txt -> aufrufen des Skripts

date=$(date +%H:%M)

case $date in
   [06:00-12:00])
      echo "Es ist Vormittag"
      ;;
   [13:00-18:00]) 
      echo "Es ist Nachmittag"
      ;;
   [19:00-22:00]) 
      echo "Es ist Abend"
      ;;
   [23:00-05:00]) 
      echo "Es ist Nacht"
      ;;
esac
```

I tried this before

Comment: welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far ? hint **date +%H**

Comment: Hint #2 Cron...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost make it

```
date=$(date +%H)

case $date in
   06|07|08|09|10|11|12)
      echo "Es ist Vormittag"
      ;;
   13|14|15|16|17|18) 
      echo "Es ist Nachmittag"
      ;;
   19|20|21|22) 
      echo "Es ist Abend"
      ;;
   23|00|01|02|03|04|05) 
      echo "Es ist Nacht"
      ;;
esac
```

- why bother with minutes ?
- you have to enumerate all hours, <s>there is no indication that bash will accept range</s> see Edit.
- if you wait a bit, I am sure perl expert will come with a shorter solution.

Edit: as per Costas's suggestion

```
case $date in
   0[6-9]|1[012])
      echo "Es ist Vormittag"
      ;;
   1[3-8]) 
      echo "Es ist Nachmittag"
      ;;
   19|2[0-2]) 
      echo "Es ist Abend"
      ;;
   23|0[0-5]) 
      echo "Es ist Nacht"
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: And in your variant you should strip off `[]`.